# Infer a reduced union type by checking for property existence?

Tags: typescript

I have a really large union type with members that have a variety of types with some overlaps. In practice these are all various types of record properties in a really large database schema.

```
    type A = { x: number; y: number }
    type B = { y: number; z: number }
    // many many more types

    type All = 
        | A 
        | B
        // many many more types
```

I have a very generic function that accepts any type and does something based on the existence of certain properties. The problem is that I cannot check for the existence of a property because Typescript will throw and error saying that some of the types in this union don't have that property. But ideally, I could check for existence and Typescript will infer the type based on the existence of that property...

```
    function f(value: All) {
        if (value.x) {
            // value must be A or anything that has an x property
        } else if (value.y) {
            // value must be B or anything that has an x property       
        }
    }
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: You're not describing a [tagged union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions); it's just a union.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
type A = { x: number; y: number }
type B = { y: number; z: number }
type C = { z: number; x: number }
type D = { y: number; w: number }
type E = { w: number; z: number }
type All = A | B | C | D | E ;

function hasKey<K extends string>(key: K, val: any): val is {[P in K]: any} {
  return key in val;
}

function f(v: All) {
  if (hasKey('x', v)) {
    v // A | C
  } else if (hasKey('y',v)) {
    v // B | D
  } else {
    v // E
  }
}
```

The `hasKey` function is a user-defined type guard which will narrow down unions for you.

Comment: Wow, I never would have found that out. Is there a library somewhere full of functions like this? There must be

Answer (score 0):

Based on jcalz Answer, I prefer an approach that does not require a dedicated library function:

```js
type A = { x: number; y: number }
type B = { y: number; z: number }
type C = { z: number; x: number }
type D = { y: number; w: number }
type E = { w: number; z: number }
type All = A | B | C | D | E ;

function f(v: All) {
  if ('x' in v)) {
    v // A | C
  } else if ('y' in v)) {
    v // B | D
  } else {
    v // E
  }
}
```

I think this approach is even better to understand by reading.